# C++ object doesn't get value when connected QML property changes

Tags: c++, qml, qt5

I have a component in C++ with the property "step":

```
class cppcomponent   : public QObject
...
Q_PROPERTY(QVariant step READ getStep WRITE setStep NOTIFY stepChanged)
```

I try to connect this property to QML.

```
TextInput {
    text: cppcomp.step
}
```

It works in one direction. QML gets the initial value. However, when I change the value in QML, my `setStep` method is not called.

It works only, when I set the property of C++ component explicitly in onAccepted:

```
TextInput {
    text: cppcomp.step
    onAccepted: {
        cppcomp.step = step.text
    }
}
```

Do I really have to set it explicitly?

Comment: How do you change the value in your QML ? You may have mixed up the binding ? Alternatively, if you only have simple getters and setters, you may want to replace your `READ` and `WRITE` with `MEMBER`.

Comment: MEMBER ? never heard of that. I will check. I change the value by simply inputting it in TextInput

Comment: Ah I see. Yeah that way you will reset the value of `text` in your TextInput and replace it with a new value, but you will not change `step`

Comment: @DuKes0mE MEMBER was a cool advice. Reduced some code :-)

Comment: Uh, right now I can't think of any other solution but setting it explicitly. Maybe someone else has a nifty idea.

Comment: @DuKes0mE I see, the bindings are not bi-directional, and it looks like it is not easy to implement that bi-directional behavior in QML. In one system I implemented it in C++ by sending the updated value of the component to all but not to the original sender. That way I avoided loops.
Many thanks!

Comment: On a side-note: if it is only one line of code, you don't need to use brackets. One-liners maybe improvees readability and speeds up the QML performance a bit. So you can also write: `onAccepted: cppcomp.step = step.text` or `onTextChanged: cppcomp.step = step.text`

Comment: No matter whether onliner or multiple lines: It will be transformed into a JS-Function. There should be no concrete performance difference. In QML bi-directional bindings can be created by using the "Binding"-Objects. They won't be overridden by a new assignment of the value.

Comment: Has the `TextInput` an `id:step`?  Is `step` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work well, except that the `step` might not be defined. If you want to get to `TextInput` property just omit its `id`. To confirm that your idea is working correctly, run this code:

```
    QtObject { //A bare QObject with one property
        id:cppcomp
        property string step: "Working"
    }

    TextInput { 
        text: cppcomp.step+"!"
        onAccepted: cppcomp.step = text
    }
```

Each time you press the <kbd>enter</kbd> when `TextInput` is focused a new `!` should appear.

(Tested with Qt 5.7)

Comment: Was not exactly the answer, but implicitly I read "yes, you should implement onAccepted". P.S.: cool trick with QtObject and omitting id